# Nginx / Plone server redirects

Tags: nginx, plone

i try to minimize my HTTP Redirects on my Server - but it fails with content urls (it works on /)

## Current Situation

Nginx does no language redirection
Plone makes it

### Nginx

http://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/

### Plone (and of course Nginx)

https://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/en

Here are not necessary redirects

## What it should be

### Nginx

http://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/en

### Plone

Nothing to do

## My Setup / Problem

If I use nginx to do all the redirections, it failed

```
map $http_accept_language $lang {
  default en;
  ~de de;
}  
server {
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri$lang;
}
```

Result

```
https://www.example.com/en/
```

which is Ok

but on content urls, it doubled the language folders:

```
https://www.example.com/en/de/some-content
```

How can I setup nginx to be aware of CMS Plone language Header/Urls?

Comment: I don't know enough about nginx configuration to help you, but it looks like your rule is applied to all incoming requests when it should only be applied to requests for exactly `/`.

Comment: You may have more luck asking questions in https://community.plone.org. Have you looked at https://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/front-end/nginx.html ?